# Display an object as a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object :

```
cars: {
    number': 1, 'overload': 1,'brand': {'0': {'porsche': [{'price': 10, 'id': 0}],'vw': [{'price': 20, 'id': 1}]}}},
```

I want to display it as a list (example for the first key)

```
Number : 1
Overload : 1
Brand:
Porsche: 
price: 10
id: 0
vw:
price: 20
id: 1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: Object.entries , object.keys but no results

Comment: Look into https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Please add the code involving `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` that didn't work to create a [mcve]

Comment: But  I have arrays in object that I want display on another line

Comment: @Sébastian did you mean to add the vue.js tag? is that what you mean when you talk about displaying it as a list?

Comment: @TheDevGuy why have you changed the json after 2 answers - I think you need to clarify what it is you want..... use more description and try to format the details better......

Answer (score 1):

The code below will display what you want I think but in terms of flexability you could create sub-components and pass through the items as props to get more control. I just wanted to illustrate in a simple way what you actually need to do in Vue to iterate through your structure....

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      obj: {"0":{"color":[{"red":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
            "1":{"color":[{"blue":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
            "2":{"color":[{"green":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
            "3":{"color":[{"yellow":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
          },
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for='(value,id) in obj' :key='id'>
    <div v-for='(rowvalue,rowid) in value' :key='rowid'>
      {{rowid}}
      <div v-for='(subvalue,subid) in rowvalue' :key='subid'>
        <div v-for='(listvalue,listid) in subvalue' :key='listid'>
          {{listid}} : {{listvalue}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This diplays:

```
color
red : 1
value : 100
brand
id : 0
price : 100
color
blue : 1
value : 100
brand
id : 0
price : 100
color
green : 1
value : 100
brand
id : 0
price : 100
color
yellow : 1
value : 100
brand
id : 0
price : 100
```

I'll leave the actual formatting and other aspects you might want to do , Hope that helps.

Comment: @TheDevGuy you have changed your question so the json no longer matches - but the question still remains answered... The same process will be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
obj = {"0":{"color":[{"red":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
 "1":{"color":[{"blue":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
 "2":{"color":[{"green":1,"value":100}],"brand":[{"id":0,"price":100}]},
 "3":{"color":[{"yellow":1,"value":100}],"brand":    [{"id":0,"price":100}]}
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key,index) {
  // key: "0", "1", "2", "3" in your case
  console.log(obj[key])
});
```

You can also do

```
for (var key in obj) {
   console.log(obj[key])
}
```

This will give you the object with "color" and "brand" properties that you want

Comment: How Can I display  like I want in Vue ?

Comment: Yes that's  almost it, but I made mistake in my object. I update code